# C++ Ray Tracing - Plane is always returning true for the whole image

Tags: c++, raytracing, plane

When attempting to render a plane in my image, the whole image is being phong shaded.  I would like to just see the plane.  I pass an array of primitives to my checkForIntersection function.  tmin is initially set to 100, if an intersection is found this changes.  If an intersection is found and tmin changes then I cast shadow rays.  This works perfectly for my spheres, but when I try to implement the plane, the whole image/background gets phong shaded.

Why the whole background is being phong shaded.  Is there something wrong with my plane intersection formula?

When the tmin line is commented: http://imgur.com/k789DP4

When the tmin line is uncommented: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx0Mc.jpg

Neither show me my plane.  Although when I set the plane to be cutting the spheres in half, it does show the cut in the ambient color.

```
// ********** Global Variables *********
RgbImage * myImage;
vec3 nEye(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
vec3 lightSource1(-2.0,-1.5,0.0);
vec3 lightSource2(0.0,-2.0,0.0);
float tmin=100.0;

struct Prim
{
    vec3 origin;
    double radius;
    double underSquare;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse_albedo;
    vec3 specular_albedo;
    float specular_power;
    vec3 light_intensity;
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 pt1;
    vec3 pt2;
    vec3 pt3;
};


// *****************Check Intersection**************
Prim checkForIntersection(vec3 point, vec3 directionVector, Prim prims[4], bool printit){
    Prim pickPrim;

    float D = 0;
    float denom = dot(prims[3].normal, directionVector);    //Is this the correct direction vector?
    float numer = dot(prims[3].normal, nEye) + D;       
    //vec3 hitTemp;
    //vec3 hitPoint;
    if (denom!=0){
        float t= -(numer) / denom;
        //cout << t << endl;
        if (t <= tmin && t>0.001 && t<6){
            //tmin=t;
            pickPrim = prims[3];
        }
    }
    return pickPrim;
}


// ***********************Calling Function**********************
Prim sphere1;
Prim sphere2;
Prim sphere3;
Prim pickPrim;
Ray shadowRay;
Ray shadowRay2;
tmin = 100;
vec3 pixelColor(0,0,1);

Prim squarePlane;
    squarePlane.ambient=vec3(0.329412, 0.223529, 0.027451);
    squarePlane.diffuse_albedo=vec3(0.780392, 0.568627, 0.113725);
    squarePlane.specular_albedo = vec3(0.992157,0.941176,0.807843);
    squarePlane.specular_power = 27.8974;
    squarePlane.light_intensity = vec3(1,1,1);
    squarePlane.normal = normalize(vec3(0,0,-0.1));

    Prim prims[4] =     {   sphere1,
                            sphere2,
                            sphere3,
                            squarePlane
                        };

    pickPrim = checkForIntersection(nEye, nVecDir, prims, false);  // last parameter is for print debugging

    if (tmin != 100){ //if tmin has changed, we found and intersection, send shadow ray
        vec3 hitTemp(nVecDir.x*tmin, nVecDir.y*tmin, nVecDir.z*tmin);
        vec3 hitPoint = (nEye + hitTemp);
        shadowRay.vecDir = (normalize(lightSource1 - (hitPoint)));
        //shadowRay2.vecDir = (normalize(lightSource2 - (hitPoint)));
        tmin = 100;  // Set tmin for a new ray trace.
        Prim tminDummy = checkForIntersection(hitPoint, shadowRay.vecDir, prims, true);

        if (tmin != 100){ //if tmin does not equal 100, we found an intersection, this point is in shadow, return ambient.
            pixelColor = pickPrim.ambient;
            return pixelColor;
        }
        else{
            pickPrim.normal = hitPoint - pickPrim.origin;
            pixelColor = implementPhong(pickPrim,nEye,hitPoint);
            //pixelColor = vec3(0,1,0);
            return pixelColor;
        }
    }
    else{
        return pixelColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why the whole background is being phong shaded.  Is there something wrong with my plane intersection formula?

Comment: You check for `tmin` changing, but your intersection checking function has the `tmin` assignment commented out - is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Sorry when it is uncommented it phong shades the whole background.  When I comment it I can still see my spheres render fine.  I've added some examples of what I mean.

Comment: Hmm - your plane's normal is set to (0, 0, -1), so i would assume the plane itself is perpendicular to the image plane, if your camera direction is set to (0, 0, +- 1) (although I don't see what you have for `nVecDir`). If that's all true, then what you're seeing should be the correct behavior - the plane should take up the whole image.